# Unity3d - C# | Filling 2 images with scripts. 1 works, why doesnt the other one work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im doing an Healthbar script in unity. It works. But the mana bar script doesnt. I also have one script with static variables for health and mana system.
I have 2 images that i want to fill when health/mana incrases.Health bar works. But mana bar doesnt. There arent any compile errors. Just the script doesnt work.

Here is the health system script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class HealthMana : MonoBehaviour {
    public static float CurrentHealth;
    public float MaximumHealth;
    public float RegenSpeed;
    public bool CanRegen;
    public static float CurrentMana;
    public float MaximumMana;
    public float RegenManaSpeed;
    public bool CanRegenMana;
    public void Awake () {
        CurrentHealth = 100.0f;
        MaximumHealth = 100.0f;
        RegenSpeed = 1.0f;
        CanRegen = true;
        CurrentMana = 10.0f;
        MaximumMana = 100.0f;
        RegenManaSpeed = 1.0f;
        CanRegenMana = true;
    }
    void Start () {

    }

    void Update () {
        if (CanRegen == true && CurrentHealth <= MaximumHealth){

            CurrentHealth = CurrentHealth + RegenSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (CanRegenMana == true && CurrentMana <= MaximumMana) {

            CurrentMana = CurrentMana + RegenManaSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

    }
}
```

And the code for ManaUI (Image 2)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ManaUI : MonoBehaviour {






    void Update () {
        Image image = GetComponent<Image>("Image1");


        float fillamount = HealthMana.CurrentMana / 100;
        image.fillAmount = fillamount;

    }
}
```

The healthUI code is the same, but it says CurrentHealth instead of CurrentMana

Comment: Oops something wrong. Currenthealth in the health systems script is 10.0f

Comment: Also  at Image image = GetComponent<Image>("Image1"); There shouldnt be "Image1"

Comment: Instead of adding comments, you can easily edit your original post.

Comment: Please elaborate what "doesn't work" mean. What result are you getting, and how is it different from the original?

Comment: It means no errors, but doesnt do whatit should do. it doesnt give errors but do nothing